# Java Jlabel Update Text

Tags: java, swing, text, jframe, jlabel

1.I am making a cookie click clone i know so mature I'm only 12 and I'm testing my abilities. I have a problem I'm trying to get a label to update but it just won't
tried everything
Also sorry in advance for weird indentation and messiness I'm not great at making good looking code
  class

```
package learning;


 import java.awt.Component;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
   import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class Learning extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
int clicks;
boolean Update;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


    new Learning().start();





}
 public void start(){

      ImageImplement panel = new ImageImplement(new ImageIcon("Cookie.jpg").getImage());   
      add(panel);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    setVisible(true);
     setSize(600,600);
     setResizable(false);
      JLabel Click = new JLabel("Clicks: " + clicks);
      Click.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN , 20));

      panel.add(Click);
      Click.setSize(100,100);

      Click.setVisible(true);
      addMouseListener(this);
     if(Update == true){
         Click.setText("Clicks: "+ clicks);
         System.out.println("Reached");
     }


}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  clicks += 1;
  System.out.println(clicks);

  Update = true;
  if(Update = true){

          Update = false;
  }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}













}
```

Other picture class

```
package learning;

import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;


class ImageImplement extends JPanel {
private Image img;




public ImageImplement(Image img) {

    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
setMaximumSize(size);
setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide only relevant pieces of code and the error/problem you are facing.

Comment: `JLabel` supports displaying images; [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). You should be calling `super.paintComponent` before performing any custom painting. Avoid using `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` and instead override the methods you need

Comment: If you use an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans, you can have it format your code automatically for you. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem #1

Swing, like most GUI's, is event driven, that is something happens and you respond to it.  This makes your program non-linear (the code doesn't progress in a straight line).

Events can happen at any time for a multitude of reasons, depending on the event.  This means...

```
if(Update == true){
     Click.setText("Clicks: "+ clicks);
     System.out.println("Reached");
}
```

Will never be `true`, because the event has not occurred at the time the program interprets this command

### Problem #2

To over come this issue, your `mouseClicked` event handler will need to know about the objects you want to update.  Currently, you are declaring your variables within a local scope, within the `start` method...

```
public void start(){
    //...
    ImageImplement panel = new ImageImplement(new ImageIcon("Cookie.jpg").getImage());   
    //...
    JLabel Click = new JLabel("Clicks: " + clicks);
}
```

You will need to change these so that they are accessible at a class instance level

```
public class Learning extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    int clicks;
    boolean Update;
    private ImageImplement panel;
    private JLabel Click

    public void start(){
        //...
        //ImageImplement panel = new ImageImplement(new ImageIcon("Cookie.jpg").getImage());   
        panel = new ImageImplement(new ImageIcon("Cookie.jpg").getImage());   
        //...
        //JLabel Click = new JLabel("Clicks: " + clicks);
        Click = new JLabel("Clicks: " + clicks);
    }
```

This will allow you to access these objects from any method within any instance of the current class.

Then, within your `mouseClicked` handler, you can update the `Click` label...

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    clicks += 1;
    Click.setText("Clicks: "+ clicks);
}
```

## Problem #3

Mouse events are contextual to the component that the `MouseListener` is registered.  This means a few things, but in your case, it's possible that the `JLabel` and `ImageImplement` could potentially block block mouse events from reaching the component that the `MouseListener` is registered to.

Instead, it might be better to add the `MouseListener` to the `ImageImplement` instead...

```
addMouseListener(panel);
```

### Additional

- `JLabel` is capable of displaying images, unless you're playing on doing some kind of image manipulation or graphical effect, it might just be easier to use it instead.
- You should be calling `super.paintComponent` in your `ImageImplement`'s `paintComponent` before doing any additional painting.
- You should avoid using `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` and instead, override these methods as you need to achieve your desired results

Comment: Thank you i know must have been a simple noob mistake